# How to add static constructor to a generic internal class in Groovy

Tags: generics, groovy, jvm, static-methods

The following code is not working because the constructor does not exist:

Constructor 'Result' in 'Result' cannot be applied to '(T, java.lang.Boolean)'

```
class External {
    class Result<T> {
        final T result
        final Boolean success

        private Result(T result, Boolean success) {
            this.result = result
            this.success = success
        }

        static <T> Result<T> success(final T value) {
            return new Result<T>(value, Boolean.TRUE)
        }

        static <T> Result<T> failed() {
            return new Result<T>(null, Boolean.FALSE)
        }

        T except(Closure<Exception> c) {
            if (success) {
                return result
            }
            throw c.call()
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand what is the issue. Pleas, does anyone know the solution?

Comment: this code is not Java, and in Java I do not get that error - even if Groovy runs on the Java Platform, this question is not about the Java Language

Comment: add `static` to your nested class `Result`.

Comment: Thanks @Valijon. That fixes it. Do you know what is the theory to support it?